# Fail to concatenate a string properly to create a link

Tags: javascript, css

I'm doing a project using Wikipedia API. I want ot create a link for every li. But fail to concatenate the right way.

**This is my code**

```
  for (var j=0; j < wikiData.length; j++) {
    var articleAuthor = wikiData[1][j];
    var articleInfo = wikiData[2][j];
    var linkAuthor = wikiData[3][j];
    domCache.$wikiArticlesList.append('<li class="articleItem">'+ '<span>' + '<a href =' + '"linkAuthor">' + articleAuthor + '</a>' + '</span>' +'<span class="shortInfo">' + articleInfo +'</span>' + '</li>'); 
    console.log(j + " " + articleAuthor);
    console.log(j + " " + articleInfo);
    console.log(j + " " + linkAuthor);
  }
```

**var linkAuthor = wikiData[3][j];**

I want to concatenate linkAuthor variable to href(bolded). I know that problem is related to apostrophes. But my brain just stuck at it, i need someone to look at it with fresh eyes. Please help me.

[Codepen project link](http://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/YWjALR)

Comment: You only need the `+` for variables, there isn't any need to use it on many normal strings. It will also make it much easier to see what your doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    domCache.$wikiArticlesList.append('<li class="articleItem">'+ '<span>' + '<a href =' + linkAuthor + '>' + articleAuthor + '</a>' + '</span>' +'<span class="shortInfo">' + articleInfo +'</span>' + '</li>');
```

Your linkAuthor was inside codes

Answer (score 1):

you can rewrite append as below. When you have to concatenate large strings of html, its best to use array join for easier debugging.

```
domCache.$wikiArticlesList.append([
 '<li class="articleItem">',
    '<span>',
        '<a href="',
            linkAuthor,
        '">',
            articleAuthor,
        '</a>',
        '</span>',
        '<span class="shortInfo">',
        articleInfo,
    '</span>',
 '</li>'
].join(''))
```